# How to implement property with parameter

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a class with a property which can be accessed only with parameter. To clear my question see how I intend to use it

Note that this is different than Indexer. Please don't flag for duplicate.

**My incomplete class**

```
public class Inventory{
    public object Options..... // I don't know how to define this property 
}
```

**How I'm going to use it**

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory();
string invLabel = (string)inv.Options["Label"];
int size = inv.Options["Size"];
inv.Options["Weight"] = 24;
```

Internally, Options reads data from a private Dictionary. Please help me on how I can define the Options property.

**Note**: This is different than Indexer. With Indexer, I can use below code:

```
int size = inv["Size"];
```

But my usage is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getter property with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088660/getter-property-with-arguments)

Comment: No. As you see, my usage is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to implement it.

```
public class Options
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> _options;

    public Options()
    {
        _options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public object this[string key] { 
        get { return _options.Single(r => r.Key == key).Value; }  
        set { _options[key] = value; }
    }
}

public class Inventory
{
    public Inventory()
    {
        Options = new Options();
    }
    public Options Options { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new Inventory();
x.Options["Size"] = 120;
x.Options["Box"] = "4 x 4 x 8";
Console.WriteLine(x.Options["Size"]);
Console.WriteLine(x.Options["Box"]);
```